# local variable 'maze' referenced before assignment ERROR

Tags: python, error-handling

So i am trying to run this program but I keep getting this weird error always... Anyone has any idea what to do?
Function is

`

```
def motion(direction):
  print("entering motion")
  print(maze)
  for r in range(row):
    for c in range(col):
      if maze[r][c] !=1:
        total =0.0
        if direction==1:
          if maze[row][col-1] != 1:
            total += probs[r][c-1] *0.1
          else:
            total += probs[r][c] *0.1
          if maze[row-1][col] != 1:
            total += probs[row-1][col] * 0
          else:
            total += probs[row][col] *0.8
          if maze[row][col+1] !=1:
            total += probs[row][col+1] * 0.1
          else:
            maze += probs[row][col] * 0.1
          if maze[row+1][col] !=1:
            total += probs[row+1][col] * 0.8
          else:
            total += probs[row][col] * 0

        elif direction ==0:
          if maze[row][col-1] != 1:
            total += probs[r][c-1] *0.0
          else:
            total += probs[r][c] *0.8
          if maze[row-1][col] != 1:
            total += probs[row-1][col] * 0.1
          else:
            total += probs[row][col] *0.1
          if maze[row][col+1] !=1:
            total += probs[row][col+1] * 0.8
          else:
            maze += probs[row][col] * 0.0
          if maze[row+1][col] !=1:
            total += probs[row+1][col] * 0.1
          else:
            total += probs[row][col] * 0.1
        else:
          pass
        motionPuzzle[r][c]=total
      else:
        motionPuzzle[r][c]= -1

  
  for r in range(row):
    for c in range(col):
      probs[r][c] = motionPuzzle[r][c]
  return 0
```

`

any then this is my main function where I initlize the variables:

```
def main():
  row =8
  col =9
  probSenseOb = 0.8
  probFalseNoOb= 0.2
  probFalseOb = 0.15
  probSenseNoOb = 0.85
  #global maze
  maze = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]) 

  probs = np.zeros([row,col])
  motionPuzzle = np.zeros([row,col])
  print("main initialized")
  function()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to Initial it on a separate cell and it still didnt work.
It runs once and then shows the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-22c9a3ac99a9> in <module>
     23 
     24 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 25     main()

2 frames
<ipython-input-81-8e4cd9b4562f> in motion(direction)
      1 def motion(direction):
      2   print("entering motion")
----> 3   print(maze)
      4   for r in range(row):
      5     for c in range(col):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'maze' referenced before assignment
```

Any one has any idea why this is happening?

I am trying to figure out why the assignment of the "Maze" value keeps going away?

Comment: `maze` is only in the scope of `main`. It's not in global scope, and you didn't use the `global` keyword anywhere. Scope is a basic element of any programming language; if you don't understand how scope works, I think you should take a very basic Python tutorial before trying to write code in it.

Comment: I tried to initialize it on a different standalone cell. Still didn't work

Comment: That's not going to solve the issue because the issue is much more basic than that. You only defined the name `maze` in `main`. You can't access the name `maze` outside of `main`, no matter what, because of scope. It seems like you ignored my suggestion to research the basics of scope in Python. If you really want help, why post here if you're not even going to follow suggestions?